# Installation of Magento 2 in Ubuntu loaclhost

Tags: installation, localhost, ubuntu

Hi I have been trying to install Magento 2 on my Ubuntu localhost. I followed the below-mentioned command.

```
 sudo composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition mag2
```

Then

```
cd /var/www/html/mag2
```

sudo find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} +
sudo find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} +
sudo chown -R user_name:www-data .
sudo chmod u+x bin/magento

Then running.

```
     sudo php bin/magento setup:install \
--base-url=http://localhost/magento2 \
--db-host=localhost \
--db-name=magento2 \
--db-user=magento2 \
--db-password=<pasword> \
--admin-firstname=admin \
--admin-lastname=admin \
--admin-email=admin@admin.com \
--admin-user=admin \
--admin-password=admin123 \
--language=en_US \
--currency=USD \
--timezone=America/Chicago \
--use-rewrites=1 \
--search-engine=elasticsearch7 \
--elasticsearch-host=localhost \
--elasticsearch-port=9200
```

But when I go the `http://localhost/magento2/. I'm getting below mention error on my browser.

```
<?php
/**
 * Public alias for the application entry point
 *
 * Copyright Â© Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

try {
    require __DIR__ . '/../app/bootstrap.php';
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo <<<HTML
<div style="font:12px/1.35em arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">
    <div style="margin:0 0 25px 0; border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;">
        <h3 style="margin:0;font-size:1.7em;font-weight:normal;text-transform:none;text-align:left;color:#2f2f2f;">
        Autoload error</h3>
    </div>
    <p>{$e->getMessage()}</p>
</div>
HTML;
    exit(1);
}

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app */
$app = $bootstrap->createApplication(\Magento\Framework\App\Http::class);
$bootstrap->run($app);
```

I try installing it by vhost which didn't work. I check all the dependences of Magento 2 like Apache2, Php and its modules, elasticsearch all the packages are working fine.

Can someone help me with resolving and debugging this issue?
One more thing when I ran the composer installation it's not asking for a Username or password as mentioned in the installation guide.

Answer (score 0):

First of the set the 777 permission of the project folder then follow as below.

Set the folder and file permission as below first.

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;                        // 644 permission for files
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;                        // 755 permission for directory
```

then run below command.

```
sudo rm -rf pub/static/frontend sudo rm -rf pub/static/adminhtml sudo rm -rf var/cache sudo rm -rf var/composer_home sudo rm -rf var/generation sudo rm -rf var/page_cache sudo rm -rf var/view_preprocessed sudo rm -rf var/log sudo rm -rf generated/code/ sudo rm -rf generated/metadata/
```

after run this command follow below command.

```
php bin/magento maintenance:enable
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento maintenance:disable
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
sudo chmod -R 777 var/ generated/ pub/media/ pub/static/
```

Note: Make sure Elasticsearch install in your localhost.

Hope it's help to you.

Comment: it's still not working all the commands run fine without any error but, getting the same error on the browser as mentioned above. Any other way to figure this out.

Comment: Share your core_config_data table data for base URL and Magento version and PHP version etc then i will help you

Answer (score 0):

Please run below commands:

php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:flush
sudo chmod -R 777 var/ generated/ pub/media/ pub/static/